# How to use transaction with int data - Firestore Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Upon creating an account the user's firestore creates a field that displays the current amount of plastics the user has.  So far, I have a button that updates that amount using the user's text field input. I've heard of something called a transaction which apparently allows one to intsead add the input amount to the overall data for it to be displayed?  How would I accomplish this in my case when the use inputs a new amount?

Code:

database.dart

```
Future<void> userSetup(String displayName) async {
  int plastics = 0;
  final CollectionReference users =
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserNames');
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String uid = auth.currentUser.uid.toString();
  users.doc(uid).set({'displayName': displayName, 'uid': uid});

//This is the field for plastics amount starting at 0.
  users.doc(uid).update({'plastics': plastics});
  return;
}
```

How I retrieve the amount data:

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
    Future<String> getPlasticNum() async {
      final CollectionReference users = firestore.collection('UserNames');

      final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;

      final result = await users.doc(uid).get();

      return result.data()['plastics'].toString();
    }
```

How I display it:

```
FutureBuilder(
          future: getPlasticNum(),
          builder: (_, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }
            return Text(snapshot.data,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amber[400], fontSize: 20));
          },
        ),
```

Currently how the user can replace the amount, but not add to it(The problem)

```
OnPressed: () async {
                    try {
                      final String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
                      FirebaseFirestore.instance
                          .collection('UserNames')
                          .doc(uid)
                          .update({
                        "plastics": int.parse(_plasticController.text),
                      });
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    } catch (e) {}
                  },
```

Answer (score 1):

I made a separate future to take care of adding:

```
final firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance; //
FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

Future<bool> addPlastic(String amount) async {
  try {
    String uid = auth.currentUser.uid;
    var value = double.parse(amount);
    DocumentReference documentReference =
        FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('UserNames').doc(uid);

    FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
      DocumentSnapshot snapshot = await transaction.get(documentReference);
      if (!snapshot.exists) {
        documentReference.set({'plastics': value});
        return true;
      }
      double newAmount = snapshot.data()['plastics'] + value;
      transaction.update(documentReference, {'plastics': newAmount});
      return true;
    });
  } catch (e) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Then I just called it when the button was pressed

```
onPressed(){
addPlastics(_plasticController.text);
}
```